# Linq to SQL - Group By and Count

Tags: c#, sql, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to convert this query (already working)

```
SELECT Building.NAME, COUNT([User].ID)
FROM BuildingUser
INNER JOIN Building ON Building.ID = BuildingUser.ID_BUILDING
INNER JOIN [User] ON [User].ID = BuildingUser.ID_USER
GROUP BY Building.NAME
```

To Linq to SQL, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Look at my trying

```
from buildinguser in db.GetTable<BuildingUser>()
join building in db.GetTable<Building>()
on buildinguser.ID_BUILDING equals building.ID
join user in db.GetTable<User>()
on buildinguser.ID_USER equals user.ID
group building by building.NAME into grpBuilding
select new
{
    building = grpBuilding.Key,
    users = 
};
```

I just need to group my Buildings and count how many users each one has.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use the the `Count` method:

```
from buildinguser in db.GetTable<BuildingUser>()
join building in db.GetTable<Building>()
on buildinguser.ID_BUILDING equals building.ID
join user in db.GetTable<User>()
on buildinguser.ID_USER equals user.ID
group building by building.NAME into grpBuilding
select new
{
    building = grpBuilding.Key,
    users = grpBuilding.Count()
};
```

Comment: This is correct.  The fact that you were counting on that specific column is arbitrary.  You weren't using distinct or anything, so this was just picking a column and COUNT'ing it based on the grouping.

Comment: Any idea if this offsets the count to the database engine, or is the counting done in the code?

Comment: @Luke Assuming that every collection in the `from`/`join` section is an `IQueryable<>`, this will translate to `COUNT() / GROUP BY` in SQL. If you've got an `IEnumerable<>`, chances are it's going to happen in memory.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thank you for the clarification.  I think it'll be useful to others too.