# SELECT COUNT (ColumnName) Group By [ColumnName] in Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to count records and group them by a specific column in Linq using C#.
Here is my SQL Statement that I would like to convert to Linq. I want to put the grouped records to an `IEnumerable<object>` or `List<object>` so that I can pass the list to my chart.

```
SELECT 
G.[Description] AS Grade,
COUNT(CASE WHEN A.ApplicationStatusId = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Pending,
COUNT(CASE WHEN A.ApplicationStatusId = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Accepted,
COUNT(CASE WHEN A.ApplicationStatusId = 3 THEN 1 END) AS Rejected,
COUNT(ApplicationId) AS Total
FROM [Application] A
LEFT JOIN Grade G ON A.GradeId = G.GradeId

GROUP BY G.[Description]
```

These are SQL results from the above SQL statement.

[image]

My Classes

```
public class Application : Audit
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime? ApplicationDate { get; set; }
        [StringLength(150)]
        public string PreviousSchoolName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string PreviousSchoolReportUrl { get; set; }
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string PreviousSchoolTransferUrl { get; set; }
        public bool? Deleted { get; set; }

        #region Foreign Keys
        [ForeignKey("Leaner")]
        public int? LeanerId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ApplicationStatus")]
        public int? ApplicationStatusId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Grade")]
        public int? GradeId { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Navigation Properties
        public virtual Leaner Leaner { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationStatus ApplicationStatus { get; set; }
        public virtual Grade Grade { get; set; }
        #endregion

        public static Application GlobalApplication { get; set; }
        public static IEnumerable<Grade> Grades { get; set; }

        #region Dashboard Preperties - No Database Mapping
        [NotMapped]
        public int TotalApplications { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string GradeName { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }

public class Grade : LookupBase
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int GradeId { get; set; }


    }

public abstract class LookupBase
    {
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

public abstract class Audit
    {
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
        public int? CreatedByOnlineUserId { get; set; }
        public int? ModifiedByOnlineUserId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq to SQL - Group By and Count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757753/linq-to-sql-group-by-and-count)

Comment: And what is you issue?  I don't see a question here

Comment: Have you tried `MyTable.GroupBy(x => x.ColumnName)).Count()`? Where `MyTable` is your table, and `ColumnName` is the property/column you want to group by?

Comment: I would like to achieve this SQL query in Linq because I am using MVC Entity Framework code first. So I cannot write SQL Queries in my MVC application.

Comment: So I want to write the Linq statement on my controller and pass the results to my View

Comment: If you are using Entity Framework, then include `entity-framework` tag and put that information in the question. It's very important, LINQ to Objects, LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities etc. are different things. Also include the `Grade` and `Application` classes.

Comment: I have added `entity-framework-7 (core)` as a tag. Below is my **Grade** and **Application** classes

Comment: `public class Grade : LookupBase
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int GradeId { get; set; }

        
    }`

Comment: My application class is too long to put it here.

Comment: @entropic this is what I have so far `var groupedApplications = from A in applications
join G in grades
on A.GradeId equals G.GradeId
join AS in statuses
on A.ApplicationStatusId equals AS.ApplicationStatusId
group A by G.Description into grpApplication
select new
{
Application = grpApplication.Key,
Accepted = grpApplication.Count(),
Rejected = grpApplication.Count(),
Total = grpApplication.Count()
};
foreach(var app in groupedApplications)
{
string accepted = app.Accepted.ToString();
string total = app.Total.ToString();
}`

Comment: On the `foreach` loop I am just checking the output to see if it is giving me the expected results. Thanks

Comment: @Linda I meant to put that classes in the question, not in the comments. You know that you can **edit** your question, right?

Comment: @IvanStoev apologies, I have edited my question with my classes now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL aggregate function `COUNT(expr)` is mapped to LINQ [`Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468851(v=vs.110).aspx) when the `expr` cannot be `null` (which is the case with your `A.ApplicationStatusId` column), [`Count(expr != null)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534807(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Sum(expr != null ? 1 : 0)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549204(v=vs.110).aspx) otherwise (I prefer the second because it seems to be translated better by EF).

So the equivalent LINQ query could be something like this:

```
var query =
    from a in db.Application
    group a by a.Grade.Description into g
    select new
    {
        Grade = g.Key,
        Pending = g.Sum(a => a.ApplicationStatusId == 1 ? 1 : 0),
        Accepted = g.Sum(a => a.ApplicationStatusId == 2 ? 1 : 0),
        Rejected = g.Sum(a => a.ApplicationStatusId == 3 ? 1 : 0),
        Total = g.Count()
    };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It worked exactly the way I wanted. Thank you so much @Ivan Stoev